How to identify which columns have been added into Sybase database Table?
I'm working on the legacy project and using Sybase DB. It appears that over the period of time columns keep getting added into the DB table, but no one has maintained what has been added. Looks like every year few fields have been.
Is there any way if we can identify which fields has been added compared to all previous version?
Through BCP utility all data have been write into FlatFile and I can see old year has few fields compared current year.
